# How to know what augmentation has been carried out tf.image.stateless_random_flip_up_down or similar API

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, data-augmentation

In TF 2.x, there are a whole set of image augmentation API, take tf.image.stateless_random_flip_up_down for example. Most of these will perform the said operation at random. What I like to find out is if there’s a way to interrogate what exactly has been perform for a specific image in a specific batch. This info is critical if the target prediction involve localization like points, bounding boxes, etc. Since affine transform (like translate) performed on image, the same operation should be used to “augment” the targets (y) in a consistent manner.

I think all the image transform API in TF2.X do not return this piece of info. I would like to see if there’s easier way than creating custom ones of my own. I have done this for the older Keras data augmentation API in the past by subclasses, and would prefer not to repeat the tedium if possible.

Comment: Update: I have since wrote some custom functions (all using tf.images.*) to solve this, although with stateful randomness. Probably will rewrite some of them to be stateless when the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your main goal is to write a data augmentation pipeline that changes both image and its labels.

Well, then I would recommend you to use Albumentaitons library instead. It is a very popular open-source library that can easily be integrated with Tensorflow and PyTorch frameworks.

Here is its documentation: https://albumentations.ai/

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: This library looks promising, I will take a closer look. For now, there maybe a few  things: (1) it may not play too cleanly with tf graph computation, esp. if you run on TPU, (2) does it support stateless randomness. (3) the integration with TF may not be as well as PyTorch. Regardless, thanks for alerting me to this lib